# Submit multiple forms not working

Tags: javascript, form-submit, multiple-forms

I am trying to implement a functionality where a website admin can delete multiple content at once by checking the checkboxes and then clicking the *SELECTED* button as shown below.

[image]

That means I have to submit multiple forms at once and I looked up a workaround online but I can't seem to get it working. Upon clicking the *SELECTED* button, the `deleteRecords()` is called. The code's shown below:

```
function deleteRecords() {

    //--- Creating array of selected rows ---
    var arrayOfIDs;
    arrayOfIDs = $('#table-style').find('[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function(){
            return $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
        }).get();   

        //-- Declaring variables ---
        var delFlagForm;   //-- form
        var action;        //-- form action
        var formID;        //-- form id
        var submitFormStr; //-- string of forms' id's 

        //--- Creating form for each row selected ---
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfIDs.length; i++) {
            delFlagForm = document.createElement("form"); //-- Creating form 
            action = "/delete_flag/" + arrayOfIDs[i];            //-- Creating action link
            formID = 'form' + i;                          //-- Creating id (form0, form1, etc)
            delFlagForm.setAttribute("id", formID);       //-- Assigning id to form
            delFlagForm.setAttribute("method", "post");   //-- Assigning method to form 
            delFlagForm.setAttribute("action", action);   //-- Assigning action to form 

            //--- Creating string of forms' id's
            if (i != 0) submitFormStr += ' #' + formID;
            else submitFormStr = '#' + formID; 
        }

        //--- Submiting forms at once ---
        //-- For the table shown above, submitFormStr = "#form0 #form1" 
        $(submitFormStr).submit(); // = $('#form0 #form1').submit();
}
```

So apparently the code displayed above, should be submiting form0 and form1 thus deleting the selected records. But, for some reason, the forms aren't submitted and nothing happens at all.

Can you spot any error?

----------- **EDIT - SOLUTION** -----------

In order to solve this problem, I tried ignoring the requests by using AJAX and is working now. Here's what the new code looks like:

```
<script>
        function deleteRecords() {
            var arr;
            arr = $('#table-style').find('[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function(){
                return $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
            }).get();   

            var delFlagForm;
            var action; 
            var formID;
            var submitFormStr;

            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                delFlagForm = document.createElement("form");
                action = "/delete_flag/" + arr[i];
                formID = 'form' + i;
                delFlagForm.setAttribute("id", formID);
                delFlagForm.setAttribute("method", "post");
                delFlagForm.setAttribute("action", action);

                ignoreRequest(delFlagForm);
            }
        }

        function ignoreRequest(form) {
            var formID = $('#' + form.id);
            var action = form.action;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: action, //action
                data: formID,

                success: function (data) {
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, text, error){
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: `$(submitFormStr).submit();` instead of `$('submitFormStr').submit();`

Comment: @DanielCorzo yeah didn't notice that flaw, but it doesn't work anyway. Nothing happens after that line of code

Comment: `if (i != 0) submitFormStr += ', #' + formID;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to submit multiple forms simultaneously. This is logical, since the default behavior when you submit a form is that the server's response is loaded as a new page.

Instead, I would recommend that you either change your HTML so that all of the values you need to submit are inside of a single form, or create an object that contains the values you want to submit, and send them to your server using AJAX (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) instead.

Comment: Each record can be individually eliminated through submitting a form where action="/delete_flag/flagId' so I don't think there's a way to group all of the values in a single one
. On another note, could you provide a simple example on how to create an object containing the values I want to submit?

Comment: Logically, all you are doing is telling your server which things to delete - if there's a technical limitation that forces you to make one HTTP request for each delete request then you either need to change your server code so that it *can* handle a request to delete multiple items, or use AJAX to submit multiple requests.

I think if you look at the documentation of jQuery's AJAX method you'll see how to create a data object and submit it. It's really very simple.

Comment: Thanks mate! I looked up a usage online and I came up with a solution. I'll post it on the OP.

Comment: @AmericanUmlaut Hello! I'm facing a similar problem. Altough you just said is not possible to submit multiple forms at once, let's say I submit one big form that contains information of multiple objects (a table, each row possess info of a object), would it be possible to diferentiate each one of these at the time of saving them into the database? I thank you for your time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47067465/core-submit-multiple-forms-and-save-each-one-of-them

Comment: @LuisAlbertoDelgadodelaFlo That's a good question and I suggest that you post it as a new question rather than a comment so that others can more easily find it and benefit from the answer!

Comment: @AmericanUmlaut Thanks for the reply :) Indeed I have asked it, in a very general way, in the given link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47067465/core-submit-multiple-forms-and-save-each-one-of-them Hope is well redacted :)